# Removing of "Std." word from the bibliography in IEEEtran reference class

Tags: bibliographies

For the `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, when we create the Standard reference, like below

```
@standard{IEC,
  title         = "{Electromagnetic Compatibility (EMC) - Part 4-2: Testing and Measurement Techniques – Electrostatic Discharge (ESD) Immunity Test}",
  organization  = "IEC",
  address       = "Piscataway, NJ",
  number        = "61000-4-2",
  year          = "2008"
}
```

The output looks like this after citation:

```
Electromagnetic Compatibility (EMC) - Part 4-2: Testing and Measurement
Techniques Electrostatic Discharge (ESD) Immunity Test, IEC Std.
61 000-4-2, 2008
```

I want to remove the word **"Std."** from the output **"IEC Std.
61 000-4-2, 2008"** so that only **"IEC 61 000-4-2, 2008"** is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

To remove 'Std.' from all @standard entries, do the following.

Find the file `IEEEtran.bst`. It contains the following section:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% STRING CONSTANTS %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
...
FUNCTION {bbl.standard}{ "Std." }
...
```

Make a copy of the file, rename it (for example `IEEEtran-no-std.bst`) and save it in the same directory as your LaTeX document. Change the line

```
FUNCTION {bbl.standard}{ "Std." }
```

to

```
FUNCTION {bbl.standard}{ "" }
```

Then change your LaTeX document to:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran-no-std}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to TeX Stack Exchange. If this answer or any other answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.